# Index Match double columns like Excel but in R

Tags: r

[image]

I am trying to do something like a Index-Match in Excel but using R.  It needs to match two columns from different data frames. Columns have similar names. I attached a picture

Thanks

Comment: `dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by = c("Part Number", "Operation"))`

Comment: Works great, thank you